# Strict Priority Scheduler Issue with Lock in priority-fifo Test

Tags: pintos

I am working on implementing a [strict priority scheduler](https://cs162.org/static/proj/proj-threads/docs/tasks/strict-priority-scheduler/) for pintos threads, but I encountered a strange issue. Here's my code:

```c
bool thread_higher_prio(const struct list_elem* a, const struct list_elem* b, void* aux){
  struct thread *thread_a = list_entry(a,struct thread,elem);
  struct thread *thread_b = list_entry(b,struct thread,elem);
  return  thread_a->priority>thread_b->priority;
}

static void thread_enqueue(struct thread* t) {
  ASSERT(intr_get_level() == INTR_OFF);
  ASSERT(is_thread(t));

  if (active_sched_policy == SCHED_FIFO)
    list_push_back(&fifo_ready_list, &t->elem);
  else if (active_sched_policy == SCHED_PRIO){
    list_insert_ordered(&fifo_ready_list,&t->elem,thread_higher_prio,NULL);
  }
  else
    PANIC("Unimplemented scheduling policy value: %d", active_sched_policy);
}

static struct thread* thread_schedule_prio(void) {
  if (!list_empty(&fifo_ready_list))
    return list_entry(list_pop_front(&fifo_ready_list), struct thread, elem);
  else
    return idle_thread;
}
```

The test I am attempting to run is `priority-fifo`. In this test, the following function `simple_thread_func` is executed:

```c
static void simple_thread_func(void* data_) {
  struct simple_thread_data* data = data_;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < ITER_CNT; i++) {
    lock_acquire(data->lock);
    *(*data->op)++ = data->id;
    lock_release(data->lock);
    thread_yield();
  }
}
```

For some reason, the lock in the `data_` parameter gets changed to a strange value (currently, I have only made the above modifications for this test, and I have not yet modified the synchronization primitives). Here's the callback I get:

```
// ... output truncated ...
vagrant@development [09:19:48] build $ pintos-test
pintos -v -k -T 60 --bochs  --filesys-size=2  -- -q  -sched=prio -f rtkt priority-fifo < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/priority-fifo.errors > tests/threads/priority-fifo.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/priority-fifo.ck tests/threads/priority-fifo tests/threads/priority-fifo.result
FAIL tests/threads/priority-fifo
Kernel panic in run: PANIC at ../../lib/kernel/list.c:216 in list_remove(): assertion `is_interior(elem)' failed.
Call stack: 0xc002ad1d 0xc002b40e 0xc002b450 0xc00233d8 0xc002371e 0xc00334a5 0xc0021693
Translation of call stack:
0xc002ad1d: debug_panic (/home/vagrant/code/personal/proj-pregame/src/lib/kernel/debug.c:35)
0xc002b40e: list_remove (/home/vagrant/code/personal/proj-pregame/src/lib/kernel/list.c:217)
0xc002b450: list_pop_front (/home/vagrant/code/personal/proj-pregame/src/lib/kernel/list.c:227)
0xc00233d8: sema_up (/home/vagrant/code/personal/proj-pregame/src/threads/synch.c:113)
0xc002371e: lock_release (/home/vagrant/code/personal/proj-pregame/src/threads/synch.c:217)
0xc00334a5: simple_thread_func (/home/vagrant/code/personal/proj-pregame/src/tests/threads/priority-fifo.c:88)
0xc0021693: kernel_thread (/home/vagrant/code/personal/proj-pregame/src/threads/thread.c:492)
```

The parameter passing seems fine until here, `aux` is still normal.

```c
tid_t thread_create(const char* name, int priority, thread_func* function, void* aux) {
//.....
  kf = alloc_frame(t, sizeof *kf);
  kf->eip = NULL;
  kf->function = function;
  kf->aux = aux;
//.....
  return tid;
}
```

Even though the panic occurs when releasing the lock, the lock was actually changed before the function was even executed. I finally tracked it down to find that the value of `aux` was already changed when entering the `kernel_thread` function:

```
static void kernel_thread(thread_func* function, void* aux) {
  ASSERT(function != NULL);

  intr_enable(); /* The scheduler runs with interrupts off. */
  function(aux); /* Execute the thread function. */
  thread_exit(); /* If function() returns, kill the thread. */
}
```

At this point, the lock in the semaphore has already been changed to an unusual value. I am not sure who called it, and the call stack looks like this:

```
kernel_thread(thread_func * function, void * aux) (\home\vagrant\code\personal\proj-pregame\src\threads\thread.c:488)
[Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code]
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the lock value is being changed and how to fix it? Thanks!

Here is the test function:

```c
struct simple_thread_data {
  int id;            /* Sleeper ID. */
  int iterations;    /* Iterations so far. */
  struct lock* lock; /* Lock on output. */
  int** op;          /* Output buffer position. */
};

#define THREAD_CNT 16
#define ITER_CNT 16

static thread_func simple_thread_func;

void test_priority_fifo(void) {
  struct simple_thread_data data[THREAD_CNT];
  struct lock lock;
  int *output, *op;
  int i, cnt;

  /* This test does not work with the MLFQS. */
  ASSERT(active_sched_policy == SCHED_PRIO);

  /* Make sure our priority is the default. */
  ASSERT(thread_get_priority() == PRI_DEFAULT);

  msg("%d threads will iterate %d times in the same order each time.", THREAD_CNT, ITER_CNT);
  msg("If the order varies then there is a bug.");

  output = op = malloc(sizeof *output * THREAD_CNT * ITER_CNT * 2);
  ASSERT(output != NULL);
  lock_init(&lock);

  thread_set_priority(PRI_DEFAULT + 2);
  for (i = 0; i < THREAD_CNT; i++) {
    char name[16];
    struct simple_thread_data* d = data + i;
    snprintf(name, sizeof name, "%d", i);
    d->id = i;
    d->iterations = 0;
    d->lock = &lock;
    d->op = &op;
    thread_create(name, PRI_DEFAULT + 1, simple_thread_func, d);
  }

  thread_set_priority(PRI_DEFAULT);
  /* All the other threads now run to termination here. */
  ASSERT(lock.holder == NULL);

  cnt = 0;
  for (; output < op; output++) {
    struct simple_thread_data* d;

    ASSERT(*output >= 0 && *output < THREAD_CNT);
    d = data + *output;
    if (cnt % THREAD_CNT == 0)
      printf("(priority-fifo) iteration:");
    printf(" %d", d->id);
    if (++cnt % THREAD_CNT == 0)
      printf("\n");
    d->iterations++;
  }
}
```

Before the first call to the  `simple_thread_func` function, the semaphore value in the lock turns into an unusual number: `3221286840` . Plus, there's an unexplained holder appearing:`0xc000efb0`.

I believe the changes I made should pass this test. Furthermore, I encountered another peculiar issue. If I change the `return thread_a->priority>thread_b->priority;` in

```c
bool thread_higher_prio(const struct list_elem* a, const struct list_elem* b, void* aux){
  struct thread *thread_a = list_entry(a,struct thread,elem);
  struct thread *thread_b = list_entry(b,struct thread,elem);
  return thread_a->priority>thread_b->priority;
}
```

to `return thread_a->priority<thread_b->priority;`, the problem does not occur. But this doesn't align with the requirement of higher-priority threads being prioritized. Also, The test results also do not meet the requirements:

```
// ... output truncated ...
(priority-fifo) iteration: 14 14 14 14 14 14 14
```